# xunit add info to output

Tags: c#, hook, integration, xunit.net

Does anyone know how to add additional info to the output console when running xUnit tests?

I'm using testdriven.net, but I don't think that is where my answer lies.

I am using a `IUseFixture` (actually `IClassFixture` from 2.0) to maintain data between tests.  When a test fails I want to output some of that contextual data along with the failure and the stack trace that you usually get.

Does anyone know of a hook I can use?

Comment: use FluentAssertions, which can help you in adding more information in case an assertions fails

Comment: use fluent-assertions...

Comment: dont use fluent-assertions ... do what the answer below says!

Answer (score 29):

You can use ITestOutputHelper to write any output to the test result view. Just let xUnit inject it into your constructor.

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
namespace xUnitTestOutput
{
    public class OutputTests
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;
        public OutputTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }
        [Fact]
        public void FirstOutputTest()
        {
            _output.WriteLine("This is output from the test!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This just saved me. It's a real shame it doesn't have more up votes and wasn't accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Apparently this does not add to the Test Detail Summary Window. One needs to click "Open Additional Output" to see the actual output.... It's a very bad UI design